# Plot multiple frequencies over time using ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2, reshape

I'm having trouble plotting frequency of one variable by group over time. Specifically, I'd like to plot a line graph where the x-axis is the month and year and the y-axis is the frequency of values for each month and year, and each group is represented by a color. This is what my code looks like:

```
library(reshape2)
library(ggplot2
r_treat<-time[,c(4,10)]
risk_treat <- melt(r_treat, id.vars="Risk_Class", variable.name="administered_date")

ggplot(data=risk_treat, aes(x=value, y=value, group = Risk_Class, colour = Risk_Class)) + geom_line() + geom_point( size=4, shape=21, fill="white")
```

[image: Frequency by group over time]

This is the `dput(risk_treat)` output:

```
structure(list(Risk_Class = c("Medium", "Medium", "Medium", "Low", 
"Low", "Low", "Low", "High", "High", "High", "Low", "Medium", 
"High", "High", "High", "High", "High", "High", "High", "High", 
"High", "Low", "Low", "Low", "Low", "Low", "Low", "Low", "Low", 
"Low", "Low", "Low", "Low", "Low", "Low", "Low", "Low", "Low", 
"Low", "Low", "Low", "Low", "Low", "Low", "Low", "Low", "Low", 
"Low", "High", "High", "High", "Medium", "Medium", "Medium", 
"Medium", "Medium", "Medium", "High", "High", "High", "High", 
"High", "High", "High", "High", "High", "High", "High", "High", 
"High", "High", "High", "High", "Medium", "Medium", "Medium", 
"High", "High", "High", "Medium", "Medium", "Medium", "Low", 
"Low", "Low", "Low", "Low", "Low", "Low", "High", "High", "High", 
"High", "High", "High", "High", "High", "High", "Low", "Low", 
"Low", "Low", "Low", "Low", "Low", "Low", "Medium", "High", "High", 
"Medium", "Medium", "Medium", "High", "High", "High", "Low", 
"Low", "Low", "Low", "High", "High", "High", "Low", "Low", "Low", 
"High", "High", "High", "High", "Low", "Low", "Low", "Low", "Low", 
"High", "High", "High", "High", "High", "Low", "Low", "Low", 
"Low", "Low", "Low", "Low", "Low", "Low", "Low", "Low", "Low", 
"Low", "High", "High", "High", "High", "High", "High", "High", 
"Medium", "High", "High", "High", "High", "High", "Medium", "Low", 
"Low", "Low", "Medium", "Medium", "Medium", "Low", "Low", "Low", 
"Low", "Low", "Low", "Low", "High", "Medium", "Medium", "Medium", 
"Medium", "Medium", "High", "Low", "Low", "Low", "Low", "Low", 
"Low", "Low", "Low", "Low", "Medium", "Medium", "Medium", "Medium", 
"Medium", "Low", "Low", "High", "High", "High", "High", "High", 
"High", "High", "High", "High", "High", "Low", "Low", "Low", 
"Low", "Low", "Low", "Low", "Low", "Low", "Low", "Medium", "Medium", 
"Medium", "Low", "Low", "Medium", "Medium", "Low", "Low", "Low", 
"Low", "Low", "Low", "Low", "Low", "Low", "Low", "Low", "High", 
"High", "High", "High", "High", "High", "Low", "Low", "High", 
"High", "High", "High", "High", "Low", "Low", "Low", "Low", "Low", 
"Low", "Low", "Low", "Low", "Low", "Low", "Medium", "Low", "Low", 
"Low", "Low", "Low", "Medium", "Medium", "Medium", "Low", "Low", 
"Low", "Low", "Low", "Low", "Low", "Low", "Low", "Low", "Low", 
"Low", "Low", "Low", "High", "High", "High", "High", "Low", "Low", 
"Low", "Medium", "Low", "Low", "Low", "Low", "Low", "Low"), administered_date = structure(c(1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = "administered_date", class = "factor"), 
    value = structure(c(2015, 2015.41666666667, 2014.91666666667, 
    2014, 2014.5, 2012.41666666667, 2013.66666666667, 2015.75, 
    2011.75, 2014.83333333333, 2014.25, 2013, 2013.83333333333, 
    2013.83333333333, 2013.91666666667, 2013.91666666667, 2014.75, 
    2014.75, 2013.25, 2014.83333333333, 2015.5, 2010.66666666667, 
    2015.83333333333, 2014.66666666667, NA, 2011.58333333333, 
    2013.5, 2013.33333333333, 2015.83333333333, 2015.33333333333, 
    2015.75, 2014, 2015.33333333333, 2015.33333333333, 2013.66666666667, 
    2013.66666666667, 2015.83333333333, 2015.83333333333, 2013.16666666667, 
    2013.16666666667, 2015.41666666667, 2015.41666666667, 2012.58333333333, 
    2012.58333333333, 2014.83333333333, 2014.83333333333, 2015, 
    2015, 2013, 2015.5, 2015.75, 2012.25, 2020.66666666667, 2013.16666666667, 
    2009.58333333333, NA, 2012.25, 2014.08333333333, 2015.83333333333, 
    2014.08333333333, NA, 2014.08333333333, 2015.08333333333, 
    2014.91666666667, 2015.75, 2014.08333333333, 2015.41666666667, 
    2014.75, 2015.33333333333, 2014.58333333333, 2015, 2013, 
    2014.58333333333, 2014.25, 2013.25, 2015.75, 2013.75, 2014.75, 
    2013.5, 2015.83333333333, 2013, 2015.58333333333, 2014.33333333333, 
    2015.5, 2014.91666666667, 2013.58333333333, 2013.41666666667, 
    2014.16666666667, 2015.75, 2015, 2014.08333333333, 2015.41666666667, 
    2014.58333333333, 2012.91666666667, 2014.41666666667, 2015.16666666667, 
    2015.08333333333, 2013.83333333333, 2013.41666666667, 2013.91666666667, 
    2015.83333333333, 2015.75, 2013.33333333333, 2014.66666666667, 
    2014.25, 2014.91666666667, 2015.33333333333, 2014.33333333333, 
    2014.58333333333, 2014.33333333333, 2014.33333333333, 2014.25, 
    2015.83333333333, 2014.16666666667, 2014.75, 2012.41666666667, 
    2013.5, 2015.5, 2014.08333333333, 2013.25, 2015.5, 2013, 
    2012.66666666667, 2015.16666666667, 2012.33333333333, 2013.41666666667, 
    2015.16666666667, 2015.16666666667, 2015.25, 2011.66666666667, 
    2015.08333333333, 2014.41666666667, 2012.91666666667, 2014.66666666667, 
    2013.16666666667, 2015.16666666667, 2013.58333333333, 2014, 
    2011.75, 2015.75, 2015.58333333333, 2011.5, 2014.91666666667, 
    2013.25, 2013.33333333333, 2005.25, 2011, 2011.83333333333, 
    2013.16666666667, 2013.91666666667, 2015.66666666667, 2014.58333333333, 
    2015.75, 2015.5, 2012.75, 2014, 2012.91666666667, 2015.66666666667, 
    2015.58333333333, 2013.08333333333, 2012.5, 2012.5, 2011.83333333333, 
    2015.66666666667, 2014.41666666667, 2015.33333333333, 2015.66666666667, 
    2013.66666666667, 2015.5, 2015.5, 2013.5, 2012.25, 2013.58333333333, 
    2015, 2015.25, 2019.25, 2013.91666666667, 2014.66666666667, 
    2015.5, 2014.41666666667, 2013.08333333333, 2013.41666666667, 
    2014.83333333333, 2014.25, 2013.41666666667, 2013.5, 2014.83333333333, 
    2015.5, 2013.75, 2014.16666666667, 2014.66666666667, 2025.66666666667, 
    2012.41666666667, 2014.66666666667, 2014.66666666667, 2013.5, 
    2013.5, 2013.25, 2014, 2014.16666666667, 2012.83333333333, 
    2013.41666666667, 2015.58333333333, 2015.16666666667, 2014.5, 
    2014.5, 2013.5, 2015.16666666667, 2014.25, 2015.66666666667, 
    2013.25, 2014.33333333333, 2014.91666666667, 2013.16666666667, 
    2014.08333333333, 2015.08333333333, 2014.75, 2012.75, 2013.41666666667, 
    2012.08333333333, 2015.5, 2005.58333333333, 2014.75, 2013.25, 
    2015.83333333333, 2014, 2013.66666666667, 2015.5, 2012.25, 
    2012.33333333333, 2015.83333333333, 2013.75, 2012.66666666667, 
    2012.41666666667, 2014.83333333333, 2012.33333333333, 2013.58333333333, 
    2014.33333333333, 2015.5, 2013.83333333333, 2014.25, 2013.91666666667, 
    2014.16666666667, 2014.66666666667, 2013.66666666667, 2012.5, 
    2015.16666666667, 2009.5, 2015.83333333333, 2014, 2014.33333333333, 
    2014.41666666667, 2013.91666666667, 2013.33333333333, 2015.25, 
    NA, 2014.08333333333, 2013.58333333333, 2013.66666666667, 
    2011.91666666667, 2013, 2012, 2014.58333333333, 2014.16666666667, 
    2012.5, 2014.41666666667, 2014.58333333333, 2013, 2015.75, 
    2012.75, 2015.66666666667, 2014.41666666667, 2014.41666666667, 
    2014.75, 2015.5, 2015.5, 2014, 2014.75, 2015, 2012.41666666667, 
    2013.91666666667, 2013.5, 2015.5, 2013.25, 2013.58333333333, 
    2014.91666666667, 2011.33333333333, 2014.25, 2013.75, 2014, 
    2015.41666666667, 2013.58333333333, 2015.08333333333, 2015.25, 
    2014.33333333333, 2013.91666666667, 2013.25, 2015, 2014.5, 
    2015.16666666667, 2015.66666666667), class = "yearmon")), row.names = c(NA, 
-301L), .Names = c("Risk_Class", "administered_date", "value"
), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: Maybe a bubble chart where the points get larger the more observations there are?

Comment: @lmo I thought about that, but I think that the simplest depiction would be 3 separate lines over time.

Comment: Can you post some of your data, try posting the output of `dput(risk_treat)`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had some trouble with the `yearmon` format, so I switched things over to a simple `Date` class.

```
## Change formatting to date class
df$value <- yearmon(df$value)
df$date <- as.Date(paste('01', df$value), format='%d %b %Y')

## Get counts for each risk class on each date
frequencies <- with(df, table(Risk_Class, date))
frequencies <- as.data.frame(frequecies)
frequences$date <- as.Date(frequencies$date)

## Plot frequencies by date
ggplot(frequencies, aes(date, Freq, group = Risk_Class, colour = Risk_Class)) + 
       geom_line() + 
       geom_point(size = 4, shape = 21, fill = "white")
```

[image]

That looks like what you are after, though I think the visualization could be improved.  It's pretty hard to see much.

I think this lets you see the data better, but that totally depends on your purpose.

```
ggplot(data= frequencies, aes(x = date, y = Freq, group = Risk_Class, colour = Risk_Class)) + 
    geom_line() + 
    geom_point( size=4, shape=21, fill="white") + 
    scale_x_date(limits = c(as.Date('2010-01-01'), Sys.Date()))
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

i improved and correct

```
df=structure(list(Risk_Class = c("Medium", "Medium", "Medium", "Low", 
    "Low", "Low", "Low", "High", "High", "High", "Low", "Medium", 
    "High", "High", "High", "High", "High", "High", "High", "High", 
    "High", "Low", "Low", "Low", "Low", "Low", "Low", "Low", "Low", 
    "Low", "Low", "Low", "Low", "Low", "Low", "Low", "Low", "Low", 
    "Low", "Low", "Low", "Low", "Low", "Low", "Low", "Low", "Low", 
    "Low", "High", "High", "High", "Medium", "Medium", "Medium", 
    "Medium", "Medium", "Medium", "High", "High", "High", "High", 
    "High", "High", "High", "High", "High", "High", "High", "High", 
    "High", "High", "High", "High", "Medium", "Medium", "Medium", 
    "High", "High", "High", "Medium", "Medium", "Medium", "Low", 
    "Low", "Low", "Low", "Low", "Low", "Low", "High", "High", "High", 
    "High", "High", "High", "High", "High", "High", "Low", "Low", 
    "Low", "Low", "Low", "Low", "Low", "Low", "Medium", "High", "High", 
    "Medium", "Medium", "Medium", "High", "High", "High", "Low", 
    "Low", "Low", "Low", "High", "High", "High", "Low", "Low", "Low", 
    "High", "High", "High", "High", "Low", "Low", "Low", "Low", "Low", 
    "High", "High", "High", "High", "High", "Low", "Low", "Low", 
    "Low", "Low", "Low", "Low", "Low", "Low", "Low", "Low", "Low", 
    "Low", "High", "High", "High", "High", "High", "High", "High", 
    "Medium", "High", "High", "High", "High", "High", "Medium", "Low", 
    "Low", "Low", "Medium", "Medium", "Medium", "Low", "Low", "Low", 
    "Low", "Low", "Low", "Low", "High", "Medium", "Medium", "Medium", 
    "Medium", "Medium", "High", "Low", "Low", "Low", "Low", "Low", 
    "Low", "Low", "Low", "Low", "Medium", "Medium", "Medium", "Medium", 
    "Medium", "Low", "Low", "High", "High", "High", "High", "High", 
    "High", "High", "High", "High", "High", "Low", "Low", "Low", 
    "Low", "Low", "Low", "Low", "Low", "Low", "Low", "Medium", "Medium", 
    "Medium", "Low", "Low", "Medium", "Medium", "Low", "Low", "Low", 
    "Low", "Low", "Low", "Low", "Low", "Low", "Low", "Low", "High", 
    "High", "High", "High", "High", "High", "Low", "Low", "High", 
    "High", "High", "High", "High", "Low", "Low", "Low", "Low", "Low", 
    "Low", "Low", "Low", "Low", "Low", "Low", "Medium", "Low", "Low", 
    "Low", "Low", "Low", "Medium", "Medium", "Medium", "Low", "Low", 
    "Low", "Low", "Low", "Low", "Low", "Low", "Low", "Low", "Low", 
    "Low", "Low", "Low", "High", "High", "High", "High", "Low", "Low", 
    "Low", "Medium", "Low", "Low", "Low", "Low", "Low", "Low"), administered_date = structure(c(1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = "administered_date", class = "factor"), 
        value = structure(c(2015, 2015.41666666667, 2014.91666666667, 
        2014, 2014.5, 2012.41666666667, 2013.66666666667, 2015.75, 
        2011.75, 2014.83333333333, 2014.25, 2013, 2013.83333333333, 
        2013.83333333333, 2013.91666666667, 2013.91666666667, 2014.75, 
        2014.75, 2013.25, 2014.83333333333, 2015.5, 2010.66666666667, 
        2015.83333333333, 2014.66666666667, NA, 2011.58333333333, 
        2013.5, 2013.33333333333, 2015.83333333333, 2015.33333333333, 
        2015.75, 2014, 2015.33333333333, 2015.33333333333, 2013.66666666667, 
        2013.66666666667, 2015.83333333333, 2015.83333333333, 2013.16666666667, 
        2013.16666666667, 2015.41666666667, 2015.41666666667, 2012.58333333333, 
        2012.58333333333, 2014.83333333333, 2014.83333333333, 2015, 
        2015, 2013, 2015.5, 2015.75, 2012.25, 2020.66666666667, 2013.16666666667, 
        2009.58333333333, NA, 2012.25, 2014.08333333333, 2015.83333333333, 
        2014.08333333333, NA, 2014.08333333333, 2015.08333333333, 
        2014.91666666667, 2015.75, 2014.08333333333, 2015.41666666667, 
        2014.75, 2015.33333333333, 2014.58333333333, 2015, 2013, 
        2014.58333333333, 2014.25, 2013.25, 2015.75, 2013.75, 2014.75, 
        2013.5, 2015.83333333333, 2013, 2015.58333333333, 2014.33333333333, 
        2015.5, 2014.91666666667, 2013.58333333333, 2013.41666666667, 
        2014.16666666667, 2015.75, 2015, 2014.08333333333, 2015.41666666667, 
        2014.58333333333, 2012.91666666667, 2014.41666666667, 2015.16666666667, 
        2015.08333333333, 2013.83333333333, 2013.41666666667, 2013.91666666667, 
        2015.83333333333, 2015.75, 2013.33333333333, 2014.66666666667, 
        2014.25, 2014.91666666667, 2015.33333333333, 2014.33333333333, 
        2014.58333333333, 2014.33333333333, 2014.33333333333, 2014.25, 
        2015.83333333333, 2014.16666666667, 2014.75, 2012.41666666667, 
        2013.5, 2015.5, 2014.08333333333, 2013.25, 2015.5, 2013, 
        2012.66666666667, 2015.16666666667, 2012.33333333333, 2013.41666666667, 
        2015.16666666667, 2015.16666666667, 2015.25, 2011.66666666667, 
        2015.08333333333, 2014.41666666667, 2012.91666666667, 2014.66666666667, 
        2013.16666666667, 2015.16666666667, 2013.58333333333, 2014, 
        2011.75, 2015.75, 2015.58333333333, 2011.5, 2014.91666666667, 
        2013.25, 2013.33333333333, 2005.25, 2011, 2011.83333333333, 
        2013.16666666667, 2013.91666666667, 2015.66666666667, 2014.58333333333, 
        2015.75, 2015.5, 2012.75, 2014, 2012.91666666667, 2015.66666666667, 
        2015.58333333333, 2013.08333333333, 2012.5, 2012.5, 2011.83333333333, 
        2015.66666666667, 2014.41666666667, 2015.33333333333, 2015.66666666667, 
        2013.66666666667, 2015.5, 2015.5, 2013.5, 2012.25, 2013.58333333333, 
        2015, 2015.25, 2019.25, 2013.91666666667, 2014.66666666667, 
        2015.5, 2014.41666666667, 2013.08333333333, 2013.41666666667, 
        2014.83333333333, 2014.25, 2013.41666666667, 2013.5, 2014.83333333333, 
        2015.5, 2013.75, 2014.16666666667, 2014.66666666667, 2025.66666666667, 
        2012.41666666667, 2014.66666666667, 2014.66666666667, 2013.5, 
        2013.5, 2013.25, 2014, 2014.16666666667, 2012.83333333333, 
        2013.41666666667, 2015.58333333333, 2015.16666666667, 2014.5, 
        2014.5, 2013.5, 2015.16666666667, 2014.25, 2015.66666666667, 
        2013.25, 2014.33333333333, 2014.91666666667, 2013.16666666667, 
        2014.08333333333, 2015.08333333333, 2014.75, 2012.75, 2013.41666666667, 
        2012.08333333333, 2015.5, 2005.58333333333, 2014.75, 2013.25, 
        2015.83333333333, 2014, 2013.66666666667, 2015.5, 2012.25, 
        2012.33333333333, 2015.83333333333, 2013.75, 2012.66666666667, 
        2012.41666666667, 2014.83333333333, 2012.33333333333, 2013.58333333333, 
        2014.33333333333, 2015.5, 2013.83333333333, 2014.25, 2013.91666666667, 
        2014.16666666667, 2014.66666666667, 2013.66666666667, 2012.5, 
        2015.16666666667, 2009.5, 2015.83333333333, 2014, 2014.33333333333, 
        2014.41666666667, 2013.91666666667, 2013.33333333333, 2015.25, 
        NA, 2014.08333333333, 2013.58333333333, 2013.66666666667, 
        2011.91666666667, 2013, 2012, 2014.58333333333, 2014.16666666667, 
        2012.5, 2014.41666666667, 2014.58333333333, 2013, 2015.75, 
        2012.75, 2015.66666666667, 2014.41666666667, 2014.41666666667, 
        2014.75, 2015.5, 2015.5, 2014, 2014.75, 2015, 2012.41666666667, 
        2013.91666666667, 2013.5, 2015.5, 2013.25, 2013.58333333333, 
        2014.91666666667, 2011.33333333333, 2014.25, 2013.75, 2014, 
        2015.41666666667, 2013.58333333333, 2015.08333333333, 2015.25, 
        2014.33333333333, 2013.91666666667, 2013.25, 2015, 2014.5, 
        2015.16666666667, 2015.66666666667), class = "yearmon")), row.names = c(NA, 
    -301L), .Names = c("Risk_Class", "administered_date", "value"
    ), class = "data.frame")

##############



    library(zoo)
    df$value <- yearmon(df$value)
    df$date <- as.Date(paste('01', df$value), format='%d %b %Y')

    ## Get counts for each risk class on each date
    frequencies <- with(df, table(Risk_Class, date))
    frequencies <- as.data.frame(frequencies)
    frequencies$date <- as.Date(frequencies$date)

    ## Plot frequencies by date
    ggplot(frequencies, aes(date, Freq, group = Risk_Class, colour = Risk_Class)) + 
           geom_line() + 
           geom_point(size = 4, shape = 21, fill = "white")
```